# Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported for simple query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have simple SQL Query and need to get the input from parameter. I am getting the when i click parameter button. Please let me know how to get the parameter if i have declare statement in my scripts.[image]
Note  :OLEDB connection manager used for connection

Answer (score 1):

You can't use parameters in an OLEDB Source if your command contains DECLARE, or anything other than a single SELECT statement.

The way to do what you want is to use build your entire SQL Command into a single SSIS variable, and use the "SQL Command from variable" option in the OLEDB source.

EDIT based on comments:

If you have to handle a SQL Command over 4000 characters, the only way to do it is in a Script Component.  The SQL Command in a script component can be any length.   [Here is an example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-source-with-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Alieman , my sql statement having more than 4000 char which is not allowed in SSIS variable as per my understanding . is there any other way creating the SP . Kindly suggest me the best practice to complete this requirements.

Comment: Can you create a Stored Procedure that contains your SQL Statement, and then just call the stored procedure from SSIS?   Also see here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559799/ssis-variable-4000-character-limit-and-spliting-it-into-two-variables

Comment: Alimen I do not want to create a store procedure because that scripts is working fine in Production. As per new requirements , we need to pass the value dynamically. How  to achieve it without creating the new  stored procedure.